# How to get the list of directories in HDFS for a specific directory pattern and pick the latest directory using Java?

Tags: java, hdfs

I need to get the latest directory from HDFS using pattern. This is what I came up with but this does not work.

The directories will be like `/mnt/output/10000000_DATA_10222019_001_RETRY_<DATE>`

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hdfsConfig);
Path srcPath = new Path("/mnt/output/10000000_DATA_10222019_001*");
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> fileIter = fs.listFiles(new Path(String.valueOf(srcPath)),
                                                            true);

while (fileIter.hasNext()) {
    String filePath = fileIter.next().getPath().toString();
    System.out.println(filePath);
}
```

Can anyone please guide me here how to do this in the correct way.

Comment: What do you mean by latest directory?  The most recent timestamp of the directory or the timestamp in the directory name?

Comment: @the date in the directory name

Comment: Haven't you several directories with the same date in their names? `"/mnt/output/10000000_DATA_10222019_001*"` looks like...

Comment: No, the Date will not be same in the directory name, it will vary. i just need to pick the one with the most recent date

Comment: what is the Hadoop version you are using?

Comment: Hadoop 3.0.0-cdh6.2.0